# How to change legend text value amcharts - PHP

Tags: php, legend, amcharts

The legend values always showing same(Last updated value).
Input is `text1` and `text2` means result is `value`+`s` for all.
Which means I cannot change the `legend.valueText`

Download from https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/blob/master/samples/area100PercentStacked.html

**Sample Code:**

```
$.each(graphValues, function (graphKey, graphValue) {       
    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.borderAlpha = 0.2;
    legend.horizontalGap = 10;
    legend.spacing = 30;
    legend.position = "top";
    legend.useGraphSettings = false;
    legend.valueWidth = 100;
    legend.labelWidth = 200;
    legend.valueAlign = "left";
    legend.equalWidths = true;
    legend.markerLabelGap = 3;                        

    /* Add prefix and suffix */     
    if (graphValue == 'text1') {        
        legend.valueText = ': $[[value]]'; //Add prefix "$"
    } else if (graphValue == 'text2') {     
        legend.valueText = ': [[value]]s'; //Add suffix "s"
    } else{    
        legend.valueText = ': [[value]]';
    }
    /* End of prefix and suffix */
    chart.addLegend(legend);
}
```

**Desired result**
`[[value]]s`   `[[value]]s`

**Expected result**
`$[[value]]`   `[[value]]s`

Please suggest me!

Comment: Could you test with the triple equals `if (graphValue === 'text1') {` and `} else if (graphValue === 'text2') {`

Comment: It would be more helpful to post your full actual code as a working fiddle rather than point to an amcharts example with your extra code. What exactly are you trying to do? You can't add multiple legends, so your code won't work at all. Are you trying to change the value displayed on the legend based on the graph's `valueField`? Have you looked at the [`valueFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueFunction) callback?